# getting the next date from long format data

Tags: r

I have a dataset that works sort of like this:

```
id= c("A1", "A1", "B2", "C3", "C3", "C3")
move= c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3)
max = c(2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
date= c("1/1/1990", "1/4/1990", "1/1/1995", "4/1/1992", "6/1/1996", "1/1/1998")
df <-data.frame(id, move, date)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date,format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Where id represents a person, move represents a move order, date represents when the move took place, and max, is the maximum number of moves a given id took.

What I want is to get a column next, that has the date of the next move.

So basically, I want to do, in pseudo code, is:
group.by(df$id), if move < max, find the row with the move+1 and return date, otherwise return NA

Which I want to end up looking like this:

```
  id move max     date  next
1 A1    1   2 1/1/1990  1/4/1990
2 A1    2   2 1/4/1990  NA
3 B2    1   1 1/1/1995  NA
4 C3    1   3 4/1/1992  6/1/1996
5 C3    2   3 6/1/1996  1/1/1998
6 C3    3   3 1/1/1998  NA
```

The dataset has over 85million observations and tons more variables, so I'd really like to avoid switching it from long to wide and back again if possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use window function `lead` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(next_move = lead(date))
```

Output:

```
id     move date       next_move 
  <chr> <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1 A1        1 1990-01-01 1990-01-04
2 A1        2 1990-01-04 NA        
3 B2        1 1995-01-01 NA        
4 C3        1 1992-04-01 1996-06-01
5 C3        2 1996-06-01 1998-01-01
6 C3        3 1998-01-01 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dttr2)
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    max = max(move),
    next_date = if_else(move < max,lead(date),NA_Date_)
    )
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
  id     move date         max next_date 
  <chr> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>    
1 A1        1 1990-01-01     2 1990-01-04
2 A1        2 1990-01-04     2 NA        
3 B2        1 1995-01-01     1 NA        
4 C3        1 1992-04-01     3 1996-06-01
5 C3        2 1996-06-01     3 1998-01-01
6 C3        3 1998-01-01     3 NA
```